# How to tell mutt not to wait for an attachment program to return?

Tags: email, mutt, mime-types

I use this line for images in my `mailcap`:

```bsh
image/*; eog %s &;
```

but mutt immediately deletes the temp file and eog can’t load it.
When I remove the `&` mutt waits for eog to be closed until it escapes from the command line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's what I use:

*.mailcap:*

```
application/*; mkdir -p /tmp/mutt \; cp %s /tmp/mutt \; xdg-open /tmp/mutt/$(basename %s) &
```

*.mutt/muttrc:*

```
folder-hook . `rm -f /tmp/mutt/*`
```

Every time an attempt to open an attachment is made, it's copied in a dedicated temp directory and the copy is opened.
Every time you start `mutt`, any lingering copies are cleaned up.

You may or may not need the `&` at the end, depending on the command you used.
(Some versions of `xdg-open` are blocking, while others are not.)

Needless to say, you can use this with any command. `xdg-open` is just a convenient one-stop handler.

Comment: This is a cool general way to replace mailcap! Thanks!

Comment: I needed the `&` after xdg-open. Can’t hurt to have it there in any case, right?

Comment: Maybe you could make a question: How to replace `mailcap` with `xdg-open`? and copy that answer over. I’m sure there are some people with that question.

Comment: Wouldn't this be problematic if you have multiple applications opened by mutt changing folders would wipe out anything in your /tmp/mutt/ folder.
Since xdg-open might or might not block I'm just using the application (firefox)

`text/html;  t=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXXXX) \; cp %s "$t" \; /bin/sh -c "firefox $t \; rm $t \;" &`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I just found it now because I am expertimenting with setting up Mutt. My solution was to use Neomutt's `shutdown-hook` instead; this just empties the tmp dir when mutt is shut down.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a wrapper command that:

1. renames the file
2. runs the viewer in background
3. cleans up when the viewer has returned instead of letting `mutt` do it.

Something like:

```sh
#! /bin/sh -

TMPDIR=$(
  mutt -D 2> /dev/null |
    awk -F\" '
      $1 == "tmpdir=" {
        gsub("~", ENVIRON["HOME"], $2)
        print $2
        exit
      }'
)
[ -n "$TMPDIR" ] || exit
export TMPDIR

nargs=$#
nfiles=0
for i do
  case $i in
    ("$TMPDIR"/?*)
      new_file=$(mktemp -ut "XXXXX${i##*/}") &&
        mv -- "$i" "$new_file" &&
        nfiles=$(($nfiles + 1)) &&
        set -- "$new_file" "$@" "$new_file" &&
        continue
  esac
  set -- "$@" "$i"
done

run_command() (
  shift "$(($nargs + $nfiles))"
  exec "$@"
)

(
  run_command "$@"
  while [ "$nfiles" -gt 0 ]; do
    set -- "$@" "$1"
    shift
    nfiles=$(($nfiles - 1))
  done
  shift "$((2*$nargs))"
  rm -f -- "$@"
) &
```

And put something like:

```
image/*; muttv eog %s;
```

Where `muttv` is that script above.

The above makes no assumption on where the filename(s) appear(s) in the list of arguments or what character they contains... Which is why we first ask `mutt` what its `tmpdir` is (so we use that to determine what are the files to *view*).

In most cases, it would be overkill though, and as Gilles points out may not work if tmpdir is specified as relative to your mailbox folder.

A simpler one would be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
nargs=$#
eval "file=\${$nargs}"
newfile=$(dirname -- "$file")/new-$(basename -- "$file")
while [ "$nargs" -gt 1 ]; do
  set -- "$@" "$1"
  shift
  nargs=$(($nargs - 1))
done
shift
mv -- "$file" "$newfile" || exit
(
  "$@" "$newfile"
  rm -f -- "$newfile"
) &
```

Replace `mv` with `cp` if you don't want to touch the original file provided by `mutt`.

Comment: Gosh, did you just write that from scratch? It took me 15 minutes to understand what you are doing and even now I’m not sure about how some parts work exactly.

Comment: Fails with my `.muttrc` because `tmpdir="=tmp"`. Why not grab the directory from the file name?

Comment: @Gilles, good point about the "+", "="... The whole point was to get tmpdir from mutt so we know which of the arguments is the file name. The whole thing is a bit overkill though anyway as in 99% of the cases the filename is going to occur only once and be the last argument, and we can just rename it to `new-$original`

Comment: Another point is that this entry script isn't always called on behalf of mutt, it could be called in circumstances where the file isn't a temporary file and must not be deleted. (I often call `see` on the command line, I don't expect it to remove the file, even if it's in `/tmp`!) Solution: make a hard link.

Comment: @Gilles, I thought of the hardlink, but for mutt, it doesn't work, because after running the command, mutt truncates the file before unlinking it. (open with O_TRUNC and close, I did verify it).

Comment: Ouch, I wonder why. In the case of [evince](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=497388), after much debate, a similar issue was solved by making evince not fork.

Comment: I’m sorry I haven’t marked it as the solution yet, haven’t had time to check if it works.